# Problem with keyboard listener in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

In kotlin android code i have an input text, i added an event listener setOnKeyListener and work fine with keyboard on my PC but when use internal mobile keyboard (i think soft kyboard not working)

```
binding.notes.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
    if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // my code...
    },
    false
}
```

This code works for physical keyboard but when it comes to native keyboard on mobile it won't work it's my big problem.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener#onKey(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) states: "there is no way to reliably catch soft input key presses", so you can't really do that. Would a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) be suitable to your use case?